# Android Emulator using Hardware Keyboard has no "Umlauts"

Tags: android-emulator, 4.2-jelly-bean, android-sdk

I have the latest ADT installed and when I start the emulator I am not able to type, for example, German umlauts.

I have tried to change the settings in android to German keyboard layout but that didn't change anything. I guess I have to configure this via AVD properties somehow, but so far I have not found a resource that explained what has to be configured where.

The configured AVD is defined as Nexus One with Android 4.2

Any idea, guys?

Comment: I think this question can be better answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, there are plenty emulator questions here, but maybe you are right. Has anyone enough rights to migrate the question?

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen Only moderators, as far as I know.

Comment: This is on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that turned out to be so easy that I didn't found any documentation about that. What you have to do is to **long press the keyboard keys just as you do in a soft keyboard**, it will show a popup with diacritics you can use for that letter (in the image you can see what happens when you long press letter "u"). Then click on the button corresponding to the character you want to use or the close button to exit.

[image: Instructions]

*(This image contains icons from [Farm Fresh Icons by Fatcow Web Hosting](http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons))*

Note that not all letters have this behavior, in which case at long pressing they repeat as normally do elsewhere.

Comment: Lol, ok, this is weird! Thanks, I wasn't thinking about that :-)